# FindSequenceFunction instantly throws an exception

Tags: warning-messages, sequence

```
FindSequenceFunction[{2, 4, 6, 7, 14, 29, 18, 5, 5, 2, 4}]
```

> SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]

```
$Version
```

> "12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)"

What's going on here? Is this a bug? Any workarounds?

FWIW, here is a screenshot, not sure if in any way useful

[image]

If I remove the last entry, the error is gone, and the command is returned unevaluated, as one would expect.

(Note: the sequence is not random. It gives increasingly better approximations to $\pi$ using `Fold[Sqrt[1 + #2^2 + #1] &, 0, Reverse @ list]`)

Comment: It does not throw an exception here... (12.0 on Mac). Have you tried quitting and restarting?

Comment: @bills Thanks for the feedback. The result in the OP is on a fresh kernel.

Comment: Not a problem here, Windows 10, same output on `$Version`